# Let $G$ be a finite group, $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $H\leq G$. Show that $[NH:N]$ divides $|H|$ and $[G:N]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $H \leq G$. Show that $[NH : N]$ divides $|H|$ and $[G : N]$.

I know that $NH<G$ and by Lagrange's Theorem,

$$\begin{align}
|G|& = [G : NH]|NH| \\
&= [G : N]|N| \\
&= [G : H]|H|,
\end{align}$$

but from here I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Show that $|NH|$ is divisible by both $|N|$ and $|H|$. Write explicitly what this means.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $NH/N \cong H/(H \cap N)$

Answer (score 0):

By [product formula of subgroups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_formula) or second isomorphism theorem, we have $$|NH||N\cap H|=|N||H|.$$
Thus $$|NH:N|=|NH|/|N|=|H|/|N\cap H|$$
divides $|H|$.

Next, since $NH\leq G$, by Lagrange's Theorem, we have $|NH|$ divides $|G|$. Therefore $|NH|/|N|$ divides $|G|/|N|$, that is, $|NH:N|$ divides $|G:N|$.